# is there a way to get the file descriptor from gzFile

Tags: c, api, zlib, file-descriptor

is there a way can i get the file descriptor  form gzFile in program C?

We can get 'fd' from File* like this:

```
FILE * file

file = fopen("myfile","rt");

int fd = fileno(file);
```

but now my i want get 'fd' from a var type of gzFile

```
gzFile gzfile = gzopen("myfile", "rt");
```

can i get 'fd' from  gzfile ?

Comment: any particular reason for this?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so, its hidden by the API.

However you could open a file using `open()` then store away its result and pass it to `gzdopen()` to get a `gzFile`.

Comment: i want to set IO buffer for gzFile  and then i want to free IO buffer according to it's fd